# height percentage not working for google map api

Tags: html

I am working on a tracking system for my laptop, I used google map api to view the current location on a map...
The height % stopped working, but only for the map canvas

Why is this?

Here is the code (sorry a little messy, still  sort of a noob...)

```
var pass_entered;
var pass_entered2;
var password="P@sSWORD";
var randomstring = Math.random().toString(36).slice(-5);
X = document.cookie.split("=")[1]
if ( X != "logged on" ) {
while (pass_entered!=password) {
    pass_entered=prompt('PASSWORD REQUIRED FOR ACCESS:','');
if (pass_entered!=password){
alert("Warning! incorrect password entered");
}}}
document.cookie = "logon= logged on; path=/";
self.close();
</script>

<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Find your device</title>
<style>
body{
height: 100;
} 
.status{
    background-color:#00003D;
}
#panel{
background-color:#CC2900;
} 
#map-canvas{
background-color:#008F00;
    height: 80;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 10px;

}

</style>

<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&signed_in=true"></script>
<script>
var geocoder;
var map;
function initialize() {
geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(-34.397, 150.644);
var mapOptions = {
zoom: 15,
center: latlng
}
map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'),  mapOptions);
}

function codeAddress() {
var address = "Fortville,Indiana";
geocoder.geocode({'address': address}, function(results, status) {
if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
  map.setCenter(results[0].geometry.location);
  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      map: map,
      position: results[0].geometry.location
});
} else {
  alert('Sorry, It seems something went wrong finding the location of your  device error code:' + status);
}
});
}

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="panel">
 <br>
 <input type="button" value="Refresh location" onclick="codeAddress();">
 <button id="lost_on" onclick="window.open( 'lost.php' , '_blank' );">Turn on  lost mode</button>
 <button id="lost_off" onclick="window.open( 'lost_off.php' , '_blank' );">Turn off lost mode</button>
 Please note you need to manually refresh the location!
 </div>
 <center>

<div id="map-canvas"></div>
<br>
<iframe class="status" src="status.php" height=40 frameborder="0" ><iframe/>
</center>
</body>
<p> Code is modified code from google map api geocoding service</p>
</html>
```

Comment: Try setting a unit, like %, on `body{
height: 100;
} `

Comment: need to add percentages when you're using them. you're missing on `body` and `#map-canvas` css.  `body { height: 100%; } ..... #map-canvas { height: 80%; ... }`

Comment: I tried adding the %, but it still doesn't work...